# Inference over time index in hidden Markov models

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, hidden-markov-model

Good evening!

I have been working with HMMs for a while now and a recent addition to my problem space sees me attempt something which I do not quite know how to google.

Assume that we have three sets of time-series observations; $\mathbf{Y}_1, \mathbf{Y}_2$ and $\mathbf{Y}_3$. Where $\mathbf{Y}_i \triangleq \{y_1,\ldots,y_N\}$. Alas each sequence has $N$ observations. Now usually one assumes that the observation example starts from the same point in time (e.g. one would start taking measurements at the start of an experiment, and then repeat this experiment multiple times, forming multiple datasets).

My model space is quite different. I am trying to model a latent stochastic process, with an HMM, and I have multiple observation sets. But they all arrive have different starting points.

A small illustration:

```
x---------------------------| measurements are taken |------o
        x-------------------| measurements are taken |----------o
                    x-------| measurements are taken |------o
```

Here I have tried to illustrate my three observation sets and the underlying dynamics. Naturally, I am not privy to the segments outside of my measurements('x' is the start and 'o' the end). The segment with my measurements is where my HMM modelling will take place.

- I would like to know if there is some way in which we can take this
  nonhomogeneous time-initialisation into account?
- Is there a way in
  which we can treat the time between 'x' and the start of the actual
  measurements, as a latent variable?
- Or how can one deal with
  basically having measurements with different time indices?

Essentially this is the problem space, where my observations have:

- $\mathbf{Y}_1 \triangleq \{y_{1+i},\ldots,y_{N+i}\}$
- $\mathbf{Y}_2 \triangleq \{y_{1+j},\ldots,y_{N+j}\}$
- $\mathbf{Y}_3 \triangleq \{y_{1+k},\ldots,y_{N+k}\}$

where $i,j,k $ are unknown.

My googling is falling short here I am afraid.